# Distorted colors on youtube after an upgrade

Tags: flash, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Flash video appears blue ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue-ubuntu-12-04-and-ubuntu-11-10)

I have Kubuntu 11.10, and after last upgrade, I'm not really sure what was it, but I assume chrome from 17 stable to 18 stable, flash plugin, youtube started showing distorted colors (in chrome and firefox).  Here is an example:
[image]
Video files from disk run fine. Also if different browser player is used (from some other site for example) the colors are good, but on youtube I have a problem. I have nvidia card with nvidia proprietary drivers if that makes and difference.

EDIT:

Some videos on youtube play with correct colors, it seems it has something to do with codecs.