# Blue people on flash videos (Youtube, Vimeo, etc...)

Tags: 11.10, firefox, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flash video appears blue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue)

After a recent update I am seeing EVERYONE in any video blue. Only the people are blue. First I was thinking it was an April Fools joke about the song Blue from Eiffel 65 but it has been 4 days already.

I tested on another 2 PCs, same problem. It started about a week ago I think.

I am using Flash 11.2.202.228 with Firefox 11.

The problem is not there if I use Google Chrome. In Chrome the Flash Player is 11.2.31.118