# Is there an easy way to change Ubuntu flavor during upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, ubuntu-netbook

I used to run Ubuntu Netbook Edition (UNE) 10.04 on my Asus Eee 901.
I recently upgraded to the "regular" Ubuntu desktop 11.10, since UNE was discontinued.
Due to the limited hardware, my netbook has become slow, which is why I want to switch to Lubuntu.

Can this switch be done easily in connection with a normal upgrade process? Ie can I install a package or edit a software sources-file somewhere, that will alter my upgrade path to Lubuntu, so that I don't have to do a complete reinstallation?

Comment: What are you upgrading from/to?

Comment: @loklaan: From Ubuntu Desktop 11.10 to (hopefully) Lubuntu Desktop 12.04.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can install Lubuntu within your existing Ubuntu installation, giving you the option to select either Unity or LXDE upon login. Alternatively, you could even completely remove Unity after installing Lubuntu in order to clear out unnecessary packages and save yourself some space.

To install Lubuntu within your existing installation, run the following command from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

To remove Unity, you have two options:

1) Remove Unity while retaining applications associated with it:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d
```

2) Remove Unity along with all associated applications:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d-places unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-services unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-applications gir1.2-unity-4.0 unity-common indicator-sound indicator-power indicator-appmenu libindicator6 indicator-application evolution-indicator indicator-datetime indicator-messages libnux-1.0-0 nuxtools
```

Comment: I just did this and it made a huge difference.

Answer (score 5):

You can install the Lubuntu package in a terminal, this will let you choose bettween ubuntu and Lubuntu without any modifications.

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Now log out and next to your user name is a little icon click it and choose Lubuntu and log back in.

Thats it you now can use the lightweight Lubuntu or the Ubuntu default desktop

If you dont want Unity anymore run this

```
sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d
```

Or if you want to get rid of all Ubuntu apps for a pure Lubuntu then this

```
sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d-places unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-services unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-applications gir1.2-unity-4.0 unity-common indicator-sound indicator-power indicator-appmenu libindicator6 indicator-application evolution-indicator indicator-datetime indicator-messages libnux-1.0-0 nuxtools
```

Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu 11.10 you can use [this guide from psychocats.net](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purelxdeoneiric) to completely remove the Ubuntu Gnome Unity packages, and do a clean install of Lubuntu desktop.

Simply copy and paste the very long command given under "REMOVE UBUNTU" in to a terminal.