# Switching to lubuntu does not work

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu

I just upgraded my older laptop to Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to try something more lightweight.

So, I installed `lubuntu-desktop` as recommended in [how to replace ubuntu with lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/373016/how-to-replace-ubuntu-with-lubuntu-13-10-without-losing-my-files) and it made no difference.

When I purged `unity` and `unity-2d`as recommended in [Is there an easy way to change Ubuntu flavor during upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181008/is-there-an-easy-way-to-change-ubuntu-flavor-during-upgrade), the unity Panel on top of the screen disappeared but no new menus are available and pressing the "start" button (on the left) does not do anything. I hoped that I would see something similar to the pre-unity ubuntu, but this did not happen.

So, how do I switch from ubuntu to lubuntu (*without* burning a CD and installing from scratch? (or at least get a working ubuntu back!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. After you install Lubuntu-desktop package, you can start to use lubuntu, I am also using lubuntu.
2. When you see the login screen, at the upper right corner, try to change it to lubuntu, then you can use it as lubuntu :)