# weird youtube player colours - channels swapped

Tags: video, flash, youtube, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flash video appears blue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue)

I am having an issue in my ubuntu 11.10 , with youtube colours being messed up - it looks as though channels have been muddled like RGB -> BGR or something.  How can I fix it?

[image]

***edit:***  it does not happen in html5 version, only in flash player.  however, some youtube videos can not be watched in html5 (e.g. ones with ads), so it is still a problem often