# Can't change Flash settings from Chrome neither Firefox

Tags: flash

I'm getting a problem since Ubuntu Natty until Ubuntu Precise, and I guess it's Unity-related.

This image describes my problem:

[image: Flash Ubuntu Problem]

I'm on my pc with Ubuntu Precise and I open any Flash content, like Flash animations on the web. I do these steps:

1. Put mouse over any Flash content;
2. Press right mouse button and choose **Settings** (my screenshots are in portuguese 'cause I'm brazilian);
3. Try changing any info on the Flash dialog that shows in the middle of screen.

Using Unity 3D, I can't change anything on that window. I can do it if I'm on Unity 2D or Gnome2, but not on Unity 3D. This happens both in Chromium and Firefox browsers.

Okay, so what's the big deal here? Sometimes I need to use some Flash-based online services that uses Mic and Webcam, like Big Blue Button web conferencing system used in distance education per example. Everytime I run a Flash content that needs to use any external device, like Mic or Webcam, the same dialog shown in step 3 pops up and asks for my confirmation to use external device. Since I'm on Unity 3D, I can't press button that gives permission for using my device on Flash, because that window stays locked. This way I end up stucked.

Anyone know a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem has been around for a while and it affects me too. Luckily, however, there is another way to edit Flash settings [here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html).

Comment: Does not allow for toggling hardware accelaration, though.

Answer (score 7):

This is known problem which happens when you are using composite manager (Unity 3D, Gnome with Compiz…) and the site with embedded Flash has scrollbars.

To make Settings window responsive, you need to use fullscreen. For example go to YouTube video, switch it to fullscreen and then open the Settings (it may take two or more attempts before the window actually opens).