# CPU spikes to 100% when trying to watch video

Tags: 12.04, video, cpu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [High CPU usage while playing Flash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128848/high-cpu-usage-while-playing-flash)

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and now CPU spikes to 100% when trying to watch a video. I don't want to hear that this is a problem with Flash or whatever...

Playing video on my machine with Ubuntu 11 was just fine. In fact I have another machine still with Ubuntu 11 and it continues to play video just fine.

Now I'm stuck with this 12.04 version and want to know how to downgrade back to version 11 as that version isn't buggy. (hence a downgrade).

Comment: need information about your hardware. CPU, Video card, Etc.

Comment: What Pc do you have and what graphic card ??? May be that U simply have to configure your video driver .

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `top` in terminal to see what process uses all your CPU. Had similar problem when was using media on external drive (NTFS) and ntfs was the problem. If it is so - just copy file from external media to your pc and wach it localy.