# Will the 'smurf effect' be solved by PepperFlash?

Tags: nvidia, 64-bit, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flash video appears blue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue)

I've got a 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 install with an Nvidia graphics card. For the time being I have disabled hardware acceleration to work around the 'smurf effect' [blue faces in videos etc].

Thinking of the future, is there a reasonable expectation that the 'smurf effect' will be resolved using Chrome and PepperFlash?

Cheers!

Comment: I've just read http://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue and applied the libvdpau1 fix. Works for me :)