# NVIDIA driver 295.53 for GeForce 120m is making things blue

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

The NVIDIA driver 295.53 for my GeForce 120m making some things blue – especially videos.

The same thing happens with the CUDA developer driver. At first I thought it was just the CUDA one, but I guess not. The thing is, my GeForce 8800 GTS on my desktop has the same driver but no problems.

What can I do?

Comment: I read it was some flash issue, just disable the driver and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure about this, but sounds like it could be related to [this bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue).

Good luck with that.

Comment: i guess the bug is a bug on some systems and not others.

Comment: i learned that there is a bug in ubuntu's nvidia drivers, so i downloaded straight from Nvidia.

Comment: From what I know, it's not recommended to use that driver. Use drivers from official repositories only. If, for some reason, you strictly need the latest edge, try this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates