# Flash player keeps crashing in firefox with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: firefox, flash

I am new to ubuntu and the last few weeks my flash player keeps crashing every time i want to watch a video. it all started when i tries to fix a problem where all of my videos were blue an strange. please help me

Answer (score 1):

I once had similar problems, both with blueish flash videos and flashplayer crashing.

I suggest you follow the solution offered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue), namely the second or third answer from above from the **community wiki**.

Every single problem I ever had with flash under Ubuntu has been solved that way.

Good luck to you and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Click in the button, it will open the software center, if you have already installed that remove, and install it again

[image: Download the flash]

and then say what you get

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problems. And none of the solutions here in the forums were helping me. So I went to the Synaptic Package Manager and installed some "things" and my youtube videos started working.

So go to Synaptic and see if these are installed, if not then do them yourself:

- Clive
- get-flash-videos
- libquvi-scripts
- libquvi7
- python-gdata
- scope-youtube

Answer (score 0):

another solution is using [flash-aid(firefox/addon)](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/flash-aid/) of [lovinglinux](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/lovinglinux)  from [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1491268)

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed description as in how to install this flash-aid by "lovinglinux"?

Answer (score 0):

Open Firefox go to help menu and pick Restart with Add-ons Disabled click restart. when it reopened a new tab will appear. Find Refresh Firefox and go through. This is the ultimate solution I've tested on Ubuntu 14.04. I hope to be useful for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you can do: (Im assuming you have flash 11)

Download this file : http://www.ziddu.com/download/20225702/libflashplayer.zip.html

Create a folder "plugins" under "/home/YOUR-USER-NAME/.mozilla/firefox/"

Like this:  /home/leopard/.mozilla/firefox/plugins

Extract the zip and copy the downloaded "libflashplayer.so" to "/home/leopard/.mozilla/firefox/plugins"

Open nautilus as Admin. Go to "/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin". Delete the "libflashplayer.so" there.

Copy the extracted "libflashplayer.so" there.

Restart firefox.

Comment: He already has Flash installed. Re-installing it is not going to help. Adobe is no longer updating Flash because even they realize how horrible their technology is.