# Flash Games performance are slower after fresh install?

Tags: video, flash, pulseaudio, facebook, html5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I installed 12.04 a week ago and everything was working smoothly: flash was working fine, I could watch HTML5 videos etc.

Last night I was trying to install W8 on the same machine. Well that didn't work out (that's a different story) so I reinstalled 12.04. Now all of a sudden I'm having two separate problems: flash games are slow and choppy, one in particular, Outernauts on Facebook, used to work fine and now it doesn't load at all; HTML5 videos are only playing at fast forward speed.

Now, I successfully fixed my issues with HTML5 using [this fix](https://superuser.com/questions/440372/html5-video-only-plays-back-at-fast-speed-on-ubuntu-linux), but I can't figure out how to make flash run as well as before (I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue/131040#131040) with no noticeable change). I have no additional drivers installed and everything is updated. I wonder if something got messed up in the new install or some recent update is causing some problem. I'm certainly confused about how a fresh install will behave in two completely different ways in such a specific thing.