# Multiple Nvidia errors

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I am one among many who seem to be having many problems with the current nVidia drivers found in the additional drivers dialog.

These issues include

1. Blue youtube videos
2. A message saying "Ubuntu has experienced an internal error"
3. Missing or wrong resolutions
4. `nvidia-settings` forgets my configuration on boot
5. Choppy video playback

The list goes on. Is there a simple fix for all of these as they are related to the same driver?

Comment: mark's solution + this solution should fix it. 


  http://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue

Comment: Agreed if you still get blue youtube  use the solution that installs a modded libvdpau1 from the link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is yes there is one simple fix for all of this just add the X-swat PPA and update your driver, mine went from version 2.9 to 3.1 I think so a good jump, and all these errors just went away.

Open a terminal and add the PPA

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Then update the repos

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally update the drivers

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now reboot, and when you log back in you will have a working, up to date nvidia driver in Ubuntu ;)

Hope this helps someone....