# How can I set the resolution on a Dell 19 inch monitor to 1368x768?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, resolution

I am using a Dell 19 inch LCD monitor.Every time I boot, I get output at  1368x768, 60Hz.
In my display settings I have set "Laptop" to 1024x768, but my monitor is compatible with 1368x768 (16:9). How can I set the resolution to 1368x768?

My graphics card is the nVidia GeForce 7025/nForce 630a, on an Asus M2N68-AM Plus motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will give you the latest drivers I could not use 1080p 60hz until I got the latest driver

Open a terminal and add the PPA

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Then update the repos

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally update the drivers

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now reboot, and when you log back in you will have a working, up to date nvidia driver in Ubuntu ;)

[Heres the original post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177039/multipul-nvidia-errors)

Also make sure you are root in the nvidia settings

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

Also make sure the two screens are separate X screens as your resolution will be limited to the lowest one (the laptop) if not.

Hope this helps and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Set it to extend display (the mode where you can drag between them) , not duplicate, as in display duplication mode they must be at the same resolution.