# Why does youtube video look weird for me?

Tags: 12.04, video, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flash video appears blue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue)

Colors look sort of blueish and and I wonder how to solve this:

[image]

Comment: Check out this question, as well as the accepted answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue