# Color config defaults to blue tint on startup?

Tags: 16.04, color-management, blueman, gnome-color-manager

Running Ubuntu 16.04. All images are "smurfed" (not just video)!?! First letter of Google is orange when I open any browser. Here's what I have tried so far:

- Reset color config (default), then restart - this fixes the problem but I don't want to have to double boot every time. It's weird because it doesn't change the configuration, but all faces are blue/blues are orange.
- Uninstalled/reinstalled color config - worked on following startup, then same old.

My current color setting is "Best RGB" so it shouldn't have blue tint like d50, d55, d60...

Comment: A screenshot would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies this is a duplicate post. The following flash player fix worked for me - https://askubuntu.com/a/128302/574603
It should be noted that this bug effects all images not just videos.
Here is the original post with several solutions:
[Flash video appears blue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue/150257#150257)

Comment: Update: Above did not fix the problem permanently, still have the blue tint.

Comment: Update: Deleting color profile then creating new color profile fixes problem temporarily on next startup until following startup reverts back to blue tint.